# Accessing getElementsByName array after Jquery Ajax IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a table list of companies with a [+] button next to each company name in my table list.
When user clicks [+], a javascript function uses jquery ajax to get and append a new table row below the row clicked, which will then display an indented list of departments.

All works great.. until we get to our beloved IE. I'm using IE 8, not tried this on prev versions.

Table list item HTML before a click:

```
<tr id="row1">
<td align="center">
<div id="button1" class="on" onclick="javascript:expandDepartments(1)"></div>
</td>
<td>Company 1</td>
</tr>
```

The onClick function:

```
    <script>
    function expandDepartments(s_cid) {
        if ($('#button'+s_cid+'').hasClass('on')) {
            $('#button'+s_cid+'').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
            if ( document.getElementsByName('rowafter'+s_cid+'').length == 0) { //if the department list does not exist for this company (first time getting departments)

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/common.php',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: 'a=getHomePageDepartments&cid='+s_cid+'',
                    success: function(txt){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#homeCompaniesList tbody').find('#row'+s_cid+'').after(txt);
                        },1000);
                    }
                });

            }else{ //otherwise, just re-show the row again, no need to request it again

                setTimeout(function(){
                    var x = document.getElementsByName('rowafter'+s_cid+'');
                    for(var k=0;k<x.length;k++)
                        x[k].style.display = '';
                    },1000);

            }

        } else if ( $('#button'+s_cid+'').hasClass('off') ) { //hide the row when MINUS image clicked

            $('#button'+s_cid+'').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
            var x = document.getElementsByName('rowafter'+s_cid+'');
            alert(x.length);
            for(var k=0;k<x.length;k++)
                x[k].style.display = 'none';

        }
    }
</script>
```

The HTML output for a company containing multiple departments:

```
<tr style="display:;" name="rowafter1"><*td data not important*..
<tr style="display:;" name="rowafter1">
<tr style="display:;" name="rowafter1">
<tr style="display:;" name="rowafter1">
<tr style="display:;" name="rowafter1">
```

Now, look at javascript function, line:
alert(x.length);

In Firefox, it alerts 5
In IE it alerts 0

Which tells me, the HTML elements injected into the page using jquery ajax are not accessible in IE and I have no idea why. Do I need to set an ajax parameter for ie?? Not sure.. please assist.

ta

Comment: What does alert(s_cid); produce in IE?

Comment: It returns the company ID being passed to the function, in this case 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName()` does not work in < IE9. If you are using jQuery, use the `attribute` selector:

```
var x = $('[name="rowafter' + s_cid + '"]');
alert(x.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

IE has [an issue with `getElementsByName`](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-411-getelementsbyname-doesnt-work.html)

Alternatively, why not use jQuery?

```
var x = $('*[name="rowafter'+s_cid+'"]'); //get all elements with name rowafterN
```