# IE not updating code after jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a calendar asp page that users schedule times and everyone's times are displayed on this table (similar to Google calendar but only month view).  I have it up and running and it works great but I need to edit the page on printing to ensure everything fits on one page.  The table is generated through an ASP loop but here is basic structure

```
<table id='calendar' class="cal">
<tr class="cal">
    <td class="cal" onclick="shoForm('5_10');">10
    <div class="cellDiv" id="5_10"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I populate this table using jQuery and AJAX so an example item under one of the cells could be like so:

```
<div id='1' class='item'>
<span name='itmUserName' id='User1'>User1</span>
<span class='dnPrint'><br/></span>
Project: <span name='tasks' id='2'>Reviewing</span>1.5 hrs
</div>
```

In jQuery, then I append items to cells like so (where `curItemDay` is the date for the item):

```
$("#"+curItemDay).append(
    "<div id='"...see above.../div>"
);
```

Now this all works fine and dandy and visually the web page loads perfect.  However, I am trying to hide certain pieces when they click on a "Print" button.

```
function printThis(){
    var names=document.getElementsByName("itmUserName");
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        if(names[i].innerHTML.split(" ").length>1)
            names[i].innerHTML=names[i].innerHTML.charAt(0)+names[i].innerHTML.split(" ")[1].charAt(0);
        names[i].innerHTML="["+names[i].innerHTML+"] ";
    }
...more code....
}
```

This works fine in FF but in IE it does not work.  When I look through the code in IE using the developer console (F12) it doesn't even show the items that were added via jQuery.  The page loads and displays everything, but the code doesn't seem to be reflecting what is on the page.

```
<td class="cal" onclick="shoForm('5_16');">
    Text - 16
    <div class="cellDiv" id="5_16"/>
</td>
```

NOTE: IE version is 8.0.6001.18702

Comment: Dynamically added elements are'nt part of the source code, they are .... wait for it .... dynamically added! The stuff you're appending is'nt valid, unless the periods and missing HTML is intended to make a point, and most browser will fix that for you, but IE probably won't.

Comment: adeneo: I realize that, but in developer console, dynamically added elements show up.  Also, they should be able to be interacted with via `document.getElementsByName`.  Issue here is that neither of those are happening in IE

Comment: And is the printThis() function triggered with window.print() ?

Comment: No it is triggered by an on-screen button.

Comment: I wonder if `getElementsByName` only targets elements that can have a name attribute and still be valid in IE8. Is `name` a valid attribute for spans (i guess that's more of a rhetorical question, of course the name attribute isn't valid for spans)?

Comment: Found the answer elsewhere, thanks for the help though.

Comment: I haven't read any of the answers or above comments, only enough of the original post to come to the conclusion that the issue is with IE only. So my advice is to just drop IE support.. just advise users to switch to a good / decent / better browser, however you want to word it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Accessing getElementsByName array after Jquery Ajax IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012984/accessing-getelementsbyname-array-after-jquery-ajax-ie?rq=1)

Changed

```
var names=document.getElementsByName("itmUserName");
```

To

```
var names=$('[name="itmUserName"]');
```

And now it works like it should.

Answer (score 1):

You are excessively abusing the `innerHTML` property.

Instead, why not do something like this:

```
<span name="itmUserName"><span class="printOn">[</span>J<span class="printOff">ohn </span>S<span class="printOff">mith</span><span class="printOn">]</span></span>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
@media screen {.printOn {display:none}}
@media print {.printOff {display:none}}
```

This will show/hide the relevant parts when the user is printing or viewing on-screen.

Comment: The data is added via AJAX/jQuery and the name comes in full so to do that I would need to split it anyway and I just find it easier to do that if the user needs to print the page rather then every time.